# PLEASE HELP. Super Confused w/ Raspberry Pi 4 SSH Setup on Mac 10.15.7

Tags: ssh, macos

Being a newb, I should have started this process 3 weeks ago so I could troubleshoot, but I'm in a hell of a bind. Trying to login to SSH on my Raspberry Pi via my Mac OSX terminal. When using the imager (via my mac) I added all of the info about my LAN, home server's IP address, etc. I keep encountering two issues:

1. Every time I get through terminal and enter the password that I’ve setup in the advanced menu via the RP imager, I eventually get a message that says, “Permission Denied,” even though it’s the exact same pw I created.
2. Alternatively, now, when I try to ssh into the Raspberry Pi by identifying ssh, the IP address of the Pi, etc., I either get an error message that says that port 22's connection is refused or -- when trying log back in via the terminal command, ssh pi@raspberrypi: "could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: nodename nor servname provided, or known." Finally, when I try to use ssh-keygen - R with my IP address, it says that the address is not found in my known hosts, even though I just sourced the IP from my system with nmap.

I've also gone in and removed all info about previous known-hosts by using the  nano ~/.ssh/known_hosts command to reset everything whenever I've had an issue. Please help.

Comment: Have you enabled SSH on the Pi?  How?  Please EDIT your question and include this information.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "my Mac OSX portal".

`ssh pi@raspberrypi` will NOT work on macOS which uses ZeroConf.

`ssh user@hostname.local` does work.

Originally the Pi used `user`pi and `hostname` raspberrypi but now encourages (forces) users to chose a unique username and encourages different hostnames.

NOTE `ssh` has been disabled by default for some time and needs to be enabled. This can be done on initial imaging or by including a file `ssh` on the boot partition.

Comment: sorry -- terminal - not portal! derp!